# How to show a widget based on a variable in flutter?

Tags: dart, widget, conditional-statements, flutter

I have a bool variable and I want to show different widgets based on that variable, for example, I want to hide the floating button when the bottom sheet is shown. how can I do that?

Comment: `build(BuildContext context) => boolVal ? Widget1() : Widget2();`

Comment: `floatingActionButton: isBottomSheetVisible ? Container() : FloatingActionButton(//....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually assign null to floatingActionButton property of scaffold in flutter when you don't want to show anything:

```
floatingActionButton: isBottomSheetVisible ? null : FloatingActionButton()
```